# Divisibility of $x^5 +2x^3 +3$ in $\Bbb Z_4[x]$ and $\Bbb Z_3[x].$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Find out if $x^5 +2x^3 +3$ is divisible in $\Bbb Z_4[x]$ or $\Bbb Z_3[x].$

In $\Bbb Z_4[x]$ I have that only with $3$ I get $3^5 +2(3^2)+3 \equiv0 \pmod{4}$ so $(x-3)$ is a divisor in $\Bbb Z_4[x]$?

Also in $\Bbb Z_3[x]$ I got that $0+0+3\equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ so $x$ is a divisor and $1^5+2(1^2)+3=6 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ which implies that $(x-1)$ is a divisor.

Using the rational root theorem I managed to factor the polynomial as $$\left(x+1\right)\left(x^4-x^3+3x^2-3x+3\right)$$ but this seems to show that $(x+1)$ is a factor of the polynomial and thus divides it?

Comment: What does 'divisible' mean in this context? Does it mean 'reducible'?

Comment: You are correct that $x + 1$ is a factor of the polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and therefore in any ring, since $-1$ is a root of the polynomial. The remaining question is how to factor $x^4 - x^3 + 3x - 3x + 3$ in both $\mathbb{Z}_4[x]$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$, if that's part of the problem statement.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In $\Bbb Z_3[x]$ the polynomial factorizes into linear factors (look at the roots).